# 3 input fields value added together with if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculation

I'm a little stuck. When an input field gets changed I want to be able to calculate all input fields, then an If statement based on the result of all input fields. any advice would be handy at this point

```
$('#form').on('change', function() { 
var a = $('#field1').val();
var b = $('#field2').val();
var c = $('#field3').val();
var $r = a + b + c;
if ( $r.value == '3')
  {
    $(".text").show();
  }
  else
  {
    $(".text").hide();
  }
 });
});
```

About the HTML.. I am wiritng this for a prebuilt form. but heres the jist.

```
<div id="form">
<input type="text" id="field1" value="0">
<input type="text" id="field2" value="0">
<input type="text" id="field3" value="0">
</div>
<div class="text">if all fields value = over 3, show this text</div>
```

UPDATE:
**https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NLOEyP#anon-login**

Comment: Can you provide the html as well?

Comment: Sorry just updated question with the HTML, Question is around the JQ and had presummed the HTML not to matter too much in this situation.

Comment: As far as know， the element <div> id is `form` does not have change event. The change event just works on elements like input, select...

Comment: The code tests for equal to 3 but the text says "= over 3", what is the intended test? Do you want it to show when the total is 3 or higher? Exactly 3? Above 3 but not exactly 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `$r.value` . It should be only `$r` .

As you using text input, it is better to use `keyup` than `change` function.

And as the values is numbers use `parseInt` to convert it from string to integer value.

```js
$('#form').on('keyup', 'input[type=text]', function() {
var a = parseInt($('#field1').val());
var b = parseInt($('#field2').val());
var c = parseInt($('#field3').val());
var $r = a + b + c;
if ( $r == 3)
  {
    $(".text").show();
  }
  else
  {
    $(".text").hide();
  }
 });
```

```css
.text{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form">
<input type="text" id="field1" value="0">
<input type="text" id="field2" value="0">
<input type="text" id="field3" value="0">
</div>
<div class="text">if all fields value = over 3, show this text</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code as below:

```
$('#form').on('change', 'input[type=text]', function() { 
var a = $('#field1').val();
var b = $('#field2').val();
var c = $('#field3').val();
var $r = a + b + c;
if ( $r.value == '3')
  {
    $(".text").show();
  }
  else
  {
    $(".text").hide();
  }
 });
});
```

Let event work on Form Element (input).

Comment: Yes, you should convert your `a,b,c` to int type using `parseInt($('#field1').val())`.  `val()` returns a string.

Comment: Sorry could you explain more? I dont know much about the parseInt()

Comment: `$('#field1').val()` returns String type. If plus strings like `"1" + "2"` returns `12`, is not **3**. So you can `parseInt("1") + parseInt("2")` will return **3**.

Comment: I'd use the selector `'#form input[type="text"]` so the event listener only targets input element inside of `#form` rather than the whole page. At this point the only inputs might be inside `#form`, but if you added input elements elsewhere on the page later, targeting all input elements could cause problems down the line.

Comment: Thanks Useless Code, will be handy down the line. but im still stuck on why it doesnt work

Comment: Among other things, in that codepen,  you are doing `parseInt('a')`; you are parsing the string `'a'`, which results in [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN). You should be doing `parseInt(a)`, parsing the value of the variable `a`. Also, once you correctly parse the numbers, the result that goes into `$r` is a number, not an object with a `.value` property. You also don't have jQuery included in that codepen... and you are targeting `'.text'` instead of `'#text'`.

Comment: (Your original code used `<div class="text">`, but that code uses `<div id="text">`).

Comment: As @BendyZhang said, `.val()` returns a string which needs to be coerced into a number before you can do arithmetic on it. [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), is one way. If need a non-integer, [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) also exists; another way to convert to a number would be to use the [unary `+` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus).